# Good structuring of JavaScript in a project?

Tags: javascript, performance, projects-and-solutions

So, I'm fairly done with the JS in my website now. It involves jQuery (and as such a .ready init)
The page has two parts, the upper is mainly Google Maps and the lower is input forms.

All of this is currently in *one* .js, functions, inits, iterations, all of it.
It's well structure and all that, everything is properly done.

My question is however: What is a good structure?
Should I be putting the upper half in one file and the lower in another?
Or should I put all the needed initializations under the .ready() and place all functions in another file?
Or should I keep everything in an ever growing file?

Comment: possible duplicate of [javascript code architecture question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1895692/javascript-code-architecture-question)

Comment: @Marius - that question seems to presume everything in one file already; this question explicitly asks about breaking things down into multiple files.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From a performance perspective, supplying all your JS in a single file to the browser as suggested by the other answers is sensible.  However, having your code built that way is not, each "class" should be in a separate file, splitting things up in to entities and a control file or two to handle the actual page calls - the same as in any other language.  These can then be combined in to one file for supply either in advance, or dynamically - preferably also minimized.

Comment: So basicly just "structured in one file"? Or is there any deeper info on control files together with JS?

Comment: Javascript works like most scripting languages (PHP, Perl, bash, etc) in that all the different `<script>` includes on a page to a degree just assemble a single page in the order referenced, the scopes are roughly the same at the top-level.  As a result, combining them in the same order in one file and using that works fine in most cases.  Though I often use query strings with JS files, and that would get broken doing it that way.

Comment: For a major JS-heavy project I can have whole libraries of JS.  If you look at the jQuery Source itself (https://github.com/jquery/jquery/tree/master/src/), you'll see it is split in to many files, but built/compiled in to a single file for production use.  See the lovely Rakefile build script (https://github.com/jquery/jquery/blob/master/Rakefile).

Answer (score 1):

Keeping the script calls to a minimum improves processing time -- each script include is a round-trip that adds time. So -- personal preference, as long as you don't care about page load times.

Yahoo's [Best Practices for Speeding Up Your Web Site](http://developer.yahoo.com/performance/rules.html) starts off with **Minimize HTTP Requests**:

> 80% of the end-user response time is
>   spent on the front-end. Most of this
>   time is tied up in downloading all the
>   components in the page: images,
>   stylesheets, scripts, Flash, etc.
>   Reducing the number of components in
>   turn reduces the number of HTTP
>   requests required to render the page.
>   This is the key to faster pages.
>
> One way to reduce the number of
>   components in the page is to simplify
>   the page's design. But is there a way
>   to build pages with richer content
>   while also achieving fast response
>   times? Here are some techniques for
>   reducing the number of HTTP requests,
>   while still supporting rich page
>   designs.
>
> Combined files are a way to reduce the
>   number of HTTP requests by combining
>   all scripts into a single script, and
>   similarly combining all CSS into a
>   single stylesheet. Combining files is
>   more challenging when the scripts and
>   stylesheets vary from page to page,
>   but making this part of your release
>   process improves response times.

Answer (score 0):

Personally, I prefer to keep all code in a single file, so the browser has to fetch only one file and not two/three/four/whatever.

But I think it's up to personal preference.